# ¿por qué hay un espacio entre la vista y el area segura en iphone x?

Tags: objective-c

Hola estoy actualizando un proyecto en Objective C pero al ver la aplicación en un iPhone X quedan espacios en negro. Qué restricciones me faltan por actualizar? o qué ajustes debo hacer. gracias

[image: anexo esta imagen]

Comment: Aquí tienes unas pautas de como elaborar una pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Al menos deberías mostrar una captura de pantalla o tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio, esta pregunta la habías realizado anteriormente, te sugerimos aportar detalles para que los miembros de la comunidad puedan ayudarte de una mejor forma, es importante edites tu pregunta, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: las restricciones son por código o a través del storyboard?

Comment: es a través del storyboard @Leemur

Comment: Problemente tengas que ajustar a 0 las restricciones Top y Bottom de tu View en el Size Inspector a la derecha de tu StoryBoard.

Comment: ya tengo ajustadas las restricciones en 0 pero se ve ese espacio en negro, no se ha que se deba @Leemur

Comment: Muestra una captura de como están esas restricciones, tal vez no estén vinculadas al objeto adecuado

Answer (score -1):

Codigo? Pero en IOS todo se trabaja con margin, En IOS por default te pone 8 de margin a cada lado , el top el status bar, bottom el tamaño del desliazdor. todos son pequeños asi que tu error debe ser en los margenes o en el margen del area segura, dependiendo si creo o no otra area y puso la constraint en esa area.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [ask], recuerda que las aclaraciones se realizan como comentario, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Esto es por la vista, puedes agregar los constraints o usar autoayout desde los storyboards. 
Tuve el mismo problema cuando la vista tiene como un tamaño fijo.

puedes ir al storyboard, selecciona el view controller, elije el table view controller y en la parte inferior le das Add New Constraints y coloca todos a cero y q muestre Standard [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]